# unreadable old storage data in SQL server using PB10.5

Tags: sql-server, sybase, powerbuilder, powerbuilder-conversion

i have problem in storage Arabic data in SQL server database,data in database table shows the characters as strange symbols that has no meaning like ÓíÇÑÉ ÕÛíÑÉ but when i read this data using PB7 it seem good and readable ,when read it using PB10.5 it seem unreadable

Answer (score 0):

Related to unicode / non unicode. Sql sever has that likely as NVarChar uniqode, and PB10.5 tries to interpret it as normal ascii,.

Check with their documentation (years that I made powerbuilder) but I would say something got lost on transposing the forms.