# Display Arabic data with PB11 and MS Sans Serif font

Tags: character-encoding, sybase, powerbuilder

We have a SQL Server 2000 database with collation set `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`

1. When exploring the table data with SQL server we can't distinguish Arabic characters(e.g. ÇæÇãÑ ÇáãÔÑæØÉ).
2. When exploring the table data with a PB7 datawindow and using `MS Sans Serif font`, Arabic data displays well.
3. When exploring the table data with a PB11 datawindow and using `MS Sans Serif font` or any other font
   arabic data does not display well (e.g. ÇæÇãÑ ÇáãÔÑæØÉ), so we can't migrate to PB11.

Could anyone advice me on how to solve the migration from PB7 to PB11 to deal correctly with latin-1 database encoding and Arabic data.

Answer (score 0):

As for your other question [unreadable old storage data in SQL server using PB10.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7650658/unreadable-old-storage-data-in-sql-server-using-pb10-5) it seems to be unicode vs. non-unicode data reading.

Was the data written by means of your PB7 application ? If so, then PB7 was not unicode aware (neither were PB8 and PB9, native unicode support was introduced with PB10) and probably sent data in your local windows encoding to the database.

You have either to migrate your existing data in the database, or to configure PB and / or your database connection to use the previous encoding.

Comment: Thanks for your replay ,but i ask how  to migrate existing data  or configure PB and database connection to use the previous encoding (not unicode).

Comment: @MohamedIbrahimEraqaty: It could be quit difficult to guess trough the Internet. You need to gather several settings to know what could be done : what is your locale (the workstation language selected), what is the unicode fallback (from the advanced tab of the regional settings), how do you connect to the db (odbc?, native driver ?), what is configured in the connection properties. To know what data is in the base and what conversion or setting to make. I am only using PB with Sybase SQL Anywhere, I am afraid not being helpful further.